# How to resize automaticaly my PyQt5 designer window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, designer, window-resize

I have a little problem with my window. I created a window using Designer (anaconda prompt> designer). Once I launch my window on my fixed PC screen no problem but when I launch my interface on my laptop (with a smaller screen), the window of the interface is much too large, it does not resize according to the size of the screen. I have looked at several forums without finding an answer.

Comment: You can get the screen resolution like here and then set the window resolution accordingly.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109629/how-can-i-resize-the-main-window-depending-on-screen-resolution-using-pyqt

Comment: Are you using layout managers (which you should)? Some widgets have fixed/minimum sizes set? Please share the ui file or the file generated from pyuic.